# Fixed decimal point numbers binary representation

Tags: binary

I saw this formula that I cannot understand how it applies (the proof).

Q: say we have a $N$ bit register (imagine a binary number with $N$ digits) for representing fixed  decimal point numbers.
In two special cases define the range in which the (whole?) "content" of the register changes:

a) decimal point is placed at the end of the register after LSB (meaning 0 digits after decimal point) ([As in this picture](http://ubuntuone.com/72hA5j7chggUQ9TIa8HeB8))

b) decimal point is placed between Sign Bit and MSB ([As In This Picture](http://ubuntuone.com/1bupg8rY0szv1NxoLV79T7))

I cannot understand what does the question refer to as "Content". Either way the answer follows:

Let $N$ be the content value, $n$ the register bits
answer to (a):
$0 \le \lvert N \rvert \le 2^{n-1}$

and answer to (b):
$0 \le \lvert N \rvert \le 1 - 2^{n-1}$

Other info:
In a $n$ bit register the Sign bit if "0" means the binary content is showing a positive number otherwise if "1" means a negative number is being represented.

MSB = most significant bit

LSB = least significant bit

For example: 6 equals (110) in binary representation with MSB=1 and LSB=0, hence (0110) represents +6 and (1110) represents -6 in a 4 bit register.

How can those formulas be applied?
thanks.

Comment: I believe the "content" is the binary number in the register